# Rotate an ImageView in a circle or around another ImageView

Tags: android, rotation, imageview

I have an Imageview (text) which I am trying to rotate 360 degrees in a circle. This is the code that I came up until now but its not doing what am looking for:

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.islay);
    ImageView circle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle);

    circle.setPivotX(circle.getWidth() / 2);

    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation1 = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotateAnimation1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotateAnimation1.setDuration(4000);
    rotateAnimation1.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    img1.startAnimation(rotateAnimation1);
```

In my code the imageview is rotating around it self not in a big circle.
I tried to solve the problem by adding another ImageView which is a circle and tried to rotate the first Image around it but couldn't figure out how its done.

[This simple drawing shows what am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQBVE.png)

Comment: Do you have any animation requirement gif file you can share?

Comment: @Jickson actually no. Am trying to do it with the code up there only. Am not sure if this is the proper way or is it possible to do it like that.

Comment: Its not straight forward to achieve it using RotateAnimation. Better look for some other animation.